# Value of Optional Type 'SKSpriteNode?' not Unwrapped; Did you mean to use ! or?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I'm trying to create a 2D SpriteNode, its stationary (its a logo), and doesn't do anything special to mess it up. This is my Code:

```
let Logo = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "logo.png");
Logo.yScale = 1;
Logo.xScale = 1;
Logo.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
self.addChild(Logo)
```

When I run the App, it crashes and gives me this error:
Value of Optional Type 'SKSpriteNode?' not Unwrapped; Did you mean to use ! or ?

It tells me to add '!' to logo (logo!), I've tried that and it still doesn't work.

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

`SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "logo.png")` call returns optional (if you do spelling mistake in file name it gives you nil).

If you are sure that file exists you can use `!`:

```
let Logo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "logo.png")!
```

but more safety way is doing it like that:

```
if let Logo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "logo.png") {
    Logo.yScale = 1
    ...
}
```

Comment: if let Logo = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "logo.png") {
    Logo.yScale = 1
    ...
    }
works but the image doesn't show up. I checked and made sure that I have the image in my assets file and its there, I changed the name to logo.png and that still didn't work. I even moved the image to a different directory. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Fixed it, Changed SKSpriteNode(fileNamed:...) to SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:...)